# Client side download to specific directory

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a web application where users are inputting data into a form. I would like them to be able to download the data that they input and is being displayed to them to a directory of their choosing (by clicking a 'save to file' button), however I am concerned that this may not be doable for security reasons. Is there a way to go about achieving this and if so how?

Comment: That's doable, and not that hard, in modern browser you can use an anchor and the `download` attribute, if you need to support older browsers it can be done with a button that submits the form to a serverside script that creates the content and sets the right content-disposition for a download

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you cannot do this client, because of security reasons. You can't access the client's file system in javascript.

So what you should do, is create the file server side and serve it as a download.